# AWS SES verifyemailidentity

Tags: .net-core, amazon-ses

I wrote the following .net code to add run time email address in AWS-SES "Email Address Identities list" and sending email to user for verification, but its not working, though the response saying "WaitingforActivation". But neither email address is added in SES "Email Address Identities" nor email went to the respective email address for verification. Any help on the same is appreciated.

```
public void SESVerifyEmailIdentity()
{
    var sesClient = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient("XXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXX", "USEast1");

    var request = new VerifyEmailIdentityRequest
    {
        EmailAddress = "Joe@example.com"
    };
    var response = sesClient.VerifyEmailIdentityAsync(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue, I was not using the right credentials for AWS. When I used my AWS credentials, its working for me.

```
   public  void SESVerifyEmailIdentity()
       {
           #region SESVerifyEmailIdentity

          var awsCredentials = new 
              Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials("YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-HERE", "YOUR-SECRET-KEY-HERE);

            var sesClient = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(awsCredentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        var request = new VerifyEmailIdentityRequest
        {
            EmailAddress = "Joe@Example.com"
        };

        var response = sesClient.VerifyEmailIdentityAsync(request);

        #endregion
    }
```